# gnome-tweak-tool doesn't start due to "ImportError: No module named gi" error

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell and have a problem with `gnome-tweak-tool`. When I click on it, it does nothing and when I try to open with terminal it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool", line 22, in <module>
import gi
ImportError: No module named gi
```

I googled a bit, found some solutions (reinstalled some `python-gobject` packages), but still didn't help./

Answer (score 11):

Little workaround found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11624982):

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool
```

Change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Should have known to do this already, had the same problem with diffuse.  Not sure why installed "binaries" seem to be so deferential towards using the current env Python.

Answer (score 1):

My file is named 'gnome-tweaks' BTW, and it was already #!/usr/bin/python
I solved my crisis by realizing that I've recently installed python3 along side
python2 and set it to default. [[  python -> python3  ]]

I changed my line to

#!/usr/bin/python2

Now it works

Comment: This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after messing with `pyenv`. I changed system python to one from `pyenv` so system could not find modules installed for system python. `pyenv global system` fixed the error.

Comment: same for me in 2023